# java 2 clients applications communicating with a server

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying out a simple `socket programming` example. I was able to run a server application and client application to communicate with each other. I now need to know a tutorial that explains how 2 clients could communicate with each other through the server.

How can I do this ? Can someone point me to a good tutorial or an explanation on how this can be done in Java

Comment: [Lesson: All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Comment: Do you want the server to establish a direct connection between the clients?

Answer (score 1):

It's not that different and difficult than writing client/server pair. You just have to create threads on server just there, where you accept connections from clients. If your clients should communicate each other, than you surely need a list to store them. And you have to implement, what your server does (communication) in this thread.
Here is a good chat programm tutorial: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/259777-a-simple-chat-program-with-clientserver-gui-optional/